# What would 'std:;' do in c++?

Tags: c++, std

I was recently modifying some code, and found a pre-existing bug on one line within a function:

```
std:;string x = y;
```

This code still compiles and has been working as expected.

The string definition works because this file is `using namespace std;`, so the `std::` was unnecessary in the first place.

The question is, why is `std:;` compiling and what, if anything, is it doing?

Comment: @Xeo: He said in the question he has `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @Fred: Derp! That part wasn't marked as code, so I just overlooked it. :) I'd still like to point to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c), however.

Comment: Same reason that `http://www.stackoverflow.com` compiles...

Comment: Yet another reason not to use `using namespace std;` :)

Comment: @KerrekSB That happened to a friend of mine while browsing reddit! The link turned out to be [this](http://i.imgur.com/q1nKF.jpg) :D

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`std:` its a label, usable as a target for `goto`.

As pointed by *@Adam Rosenfield* in a comment, it is a legal label name.

*C++03 §6.1/1:*

> Labels have their own name space and do not interfere with other identifiers.

Comment: AFAIK labels has their own name space, so they never conflict with anything else, other than keywords or macros, of course.

Comment: C++03 §6.1/1 says "Labels have their own name space and do not
interfere with other identifiers."

Comment: 6.1/1: "Labels have their own name space and do not
interfere with other identifiers"

Answer (score 32):

It's a label, followed by an empty statement, followed by the declaration of a string `x`.

Answer (score 12):

Its a label which is followed by the string

Answer (score 8):

```
(expression)std: (end of expression); (another expression)string x = y;
```

Comment: Grammar-wise, it's actually a `(label-)statement`, not an `expression`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler tells you what is going on:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  std:;cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
}
```

Both gcc and clang give a pretty clear warning:

```
std.cpp:4:3: warning: unused label 'std' [-Wunused-label]
  std:;cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
  ^~~~
1 warning generated.
```

**The take away from this story: always compile your code with warnings enabled** (e.g. `-Wall`).